# can't edit certain fields in Postgres database

Tags: sql, postgresql

Fairly new Postgres user so I apologize if this is simple and I've just missed how to handle it in my research.

I had a large update that I had to cancel.  Afterwards I can't update the fields that were set for the update.  No update happened.  Now, I can't update those fields.  I can update other records in the table.  I can also update other fields in those records but not that one field.

I made sure any outstanding queries were killed via pg_terminate and the only thing I see in pg_locks is the query for pg_locks itself.  Any ideas?

Version is 9.2.4 on Linux.

Comment: What's the error that database gives?

Comment: I don't get an error.  That's why I've gotten so stumped.  If I do an update I get the response that the row(s) are updated but there is no actual change.

Comment: You would need to add the table structures, some example data and your update statements into the question.

Comment: Anything relevant in the log files?